# Relaxation method Python

Tags: python

I am having a difficult time trying to understand the relaxation with an accuracy. I am trying to solve an equation `x = 1-math.exp((-c * x))`.

While my `c` must = `2`, it also asks for an accuracy of at least `10^-6`.

How would I tell Python to converge this relaxation or how would I solve this in Python in general?

Comment: You can try using `SymPy` for "exact" solutions. Once you install SymPy, you could just do: `x = sympy.Symbol('x'); sympy.solvers.solve(x-1+sympy.exp(-2*x),x)[0].evalf();` to yield the answer of `0.796812130020020` which checks out if you plug it back into the equation.